# forbidden folder name in apache?

Tags: permissions, apache2, directory

I have a little web server I run to help me at work. In an effort to neaten up the internal bits, I made a folder named "doc" for documents.

When i try to navigate to that folder I get `You don't have permission to access /doc/ on this server.` So then, i looked at the permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 J0h J0h     4096 Nov  7 22:46 doc/
drwxrwxr-x  5 J0h J0h     4096 Nov  6 12:35 ece/
drwxrwxr-x  2 J0h J0h     4096 Nov  6 12:35 exe/
```

permissions of "doc" looks legit. `ece/` and `exe` both work, and have the same permissions.

So then I changed the name of the folder `doc` to `docs` and it works. So evidently the folder-name doc is a black listed folder name? is that right? what is going one here?

Comment: downvoters: Please specify the reason for downvote.

Comment: @Jobin if I have to guess, someone was voting to close this question.

Comment: I got my answer, close it if you like I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most default installations of apache have a redirection that `/doc/` points to `/usr/share/doc/` that you can read the apache documentation when browsing to `http://localhost/doc/`. You have to look in your apache configuration `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or other files in the folder `/etc/apache2/` to find out.

If it's not that please add to your question what `/var/log/apache2/error.log` says when you navigate to this folder via web browser.

Comment: [Fri Nov 08 03:32:11 2013] [error] [client 130.111.192.13] client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/doc/
I will look into this. Thank you Chaos!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a folder "Documents" in your `/home/$USER` folder where you should be keeping your documents(not necessarily, but keeps thing organised).

Secondly, there are no blacklisted folders on linux(let alone on Ubuntu), if they are created by you, you should have the access to it(because you are the owner). Are you sure you are looking at the right folder's permissions?